# Handling the MongoDB _id Required field

Tags: c#, mongodb

When inserting objects to MongoDB collection the _id field is optional.
If the object is missing the _id field MongoDB collection will auto-generate it.
But when fetching from MongoDB collection to the object type then an exception will be thrown from MongoDB telling you that the _id field is missing from the object type.

We have a large solution with a lot of different common object entities for serving all the solution projects.
Some need caching (storing) in MongoDB.
We need to eliminate having the _id field on them because it's only relevant to MongoDB.
Is it possible in some way?

Comment: Inserting the _id field is optional in the sense that you have the option to provide it.  MongoDB objects require a unique identifier and will create one if one is not provided.


Do you simply want to not show the _id when you are querying your database?  If so you can project the _id field out of the results.


For instance,  db.emails.find({Email: "user1@example.com", {_id: 0})

Comment: @dyouberg we are not working with any database. The common object entities serves a diverse functions in the solution. Also it's a bad design to expose MongoDBs concrete implementation properties on common solution classes.